# Meteor cordova turn white screen when offline

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

My meteor Cordova app will turn white screen when there is no internet connection. i want to copy my code here too but i still don't know what is the problem that causing this. the only two cordova-puligins i add is 
cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp@1.4.1
phonegap-plugin-mobile-accessibility@1.0.5
The app will work just fine when there is internet connection.

Comment: The screen turns white when a hot code push is happening, I haven't seen it happen when it's offline. Can you inspect the browser console and see if there is any kind of error message? Or what the HTML is?

Comment: There is no error message except the device ready didn't fire after 5 second which is normal when disconnected from internet

Comment: Right, so you are just talking about startup? Are your routes waiting for data to be ready before rendering?

Comment: no if i run it in website it work fine. i suspect it have problem with authentication route trigger. whenever internet back online everything will render back just fine

Comment: That's my point, I'm talking about when running on the device - if your route is not resolving, the app is waiting for data, and hence the blank screen. You might need to add a timeout in your resolve to make sure that it renders the page

Comment: i tried to comment and delete all route leave only template with <h1> tag still not working

Comment: It doesn't make sense... Can you share a repo with me and I'll have a look?

Comment: thank you, after track the file one by one i finally found a left over javascript by previous co-coder in the config file hide deep inside client folder. solved the issues now

Comment: Good work @potato!

Comment: thank for helpiong @mikkel